# SQL Server Agent Job for Azure SQL Database failing

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a SQL Server set up on an Azure VM.  It's sole purpose it's to run Agent Jobs for my Azure SQL Databases.

I first created a linked server to the Azure SQL Database called AZURE_SEARCH.  I created it with Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server, and used security settings "be made using this security context" and used the Azure SQL Database admin login (which has full permissions) in the Remote Login and With Password fields. I've Tested the Connection and it succeeds.

Next I created an Agent Job with one step, a T-SQL statement that looks like this"

```
TRUNCATE table [AZURE_SEARCH].[Search_Prod].[Data].ErrorLog
GO
```

In the above, AZURE_SEARCH is the Linked Server, Search_Prod is the database, and Data.ErrorLog is the table.

When trying to execute this I receive this error:

```
The Job failed.  The Job was invoked by User sqladmin.
Executed as user: NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT. Cannot find the object
"ErrorLog" because it does not exist or you do not have
permissions. [SQLSTATE 42S02] (Error 4701). The step failed.
```

The table most certainly exists, so this must be a permissions issue. Is it possible that the Azure SQL Database is throwing a permissions error due to the fact that this the job is invoked by a different SQL Server?  From all the research I did here, as long as you set up a Linked Server to the Azure SQL Database as I outlined above, the Agent Job should have all the permissions that the Remote Login credentials have.

EDIT - I've confirmed that I AM able to do a simple SELECT query w/o issue, so this is definitely a permissions issue.  If my Linked Server is logged into with the full permissions account, why don't I have full permissions from my Agent Job?  Clearly Azure SQL Database considers me to be connected as someone else?

Comment: Your ID has permission doesn't mean NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT has permission.

Comment: Yes, however in my research for the best way to set up an Agent Job to perform tasks on Azure SQL Databases, I read that you set up a Linked Server to the Azure SQL Database, and fill the Security parameters (as mentioned above) with the login for the Azure SQL Database, and that this would work.  So why is it looking at SQLSERVERAGENT as the user instead of the user I indicated in the settings of the Linked Server?

Comment: The error message: Executed as user: NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT.  You can give a try, change SQL Agent service account to your Windows ID, then execute the job, see if it works.